# Dictionary as string in django template

Tags: django, dictionary

I have a dictionary in this format:

```
dict = [{
         "key1": "value1"
         "key2": "value2"
         "key3": "{"name": "", "age": "", "sex": ""}"
       },
     ]
```

NOTE: key3 is a string holding a dictionary

On the template I can actually pull key1, key2, key3 since they are straight forward. But, key3 is one more dictionary stored in string.

I'm able to do this:

```
{% for eachObj in dict%}
   { eachObj.key1 }
   { eachObj.key3 } <!-- This prints whole dictionary-->
   { eachObj.key3.name } <!-- This line doesn't work since it is a string -->
{%endfor%}
```

Is there some way where I can try doing like: JSON.parse(eachObj.key3).name inside that for loop?

Comment: Can't you modify the original dictionary before passing it to the template? I mean extract the value of key3, convert it to a dictionary and then substitute it to the original value. Then simply pass the new dictionary to the template.

Comment: @TajinderSingh Yes. I tried that and it is working. But, I need to run a for loop again for that dictionary. Just to avoid that extra for loop, I'm trying to parse it while looping in html template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out that we can use script tags inside for loop. I've done parsing inside that script tags and printed value using innerHTML.

```
{%for eachObject in dict%}
   {{eachObject.key1}}
   <span id='key'></span>
   <script>
     var key3="{{eachObject.key3}}"
     // console key3 and check if it has got &quot instead of '. It happend in my case. If so, add the below line:
     key3 = JSON.parse(key3.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
     // if your key3 is without &quot, then do JSON.parse(key3) in above line
     document.getElementById("key").innerHTML=key3.name
   </script>
{%endfor%}
```

Make a note to keep span tags above script tags

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work then..
You create a custom filter:
**in templatetags/my_filters.py:**

```py
import json

@register.filter
def json_loads(value):
    return json.loads(value)
```

**in your template:**

```
{% load my_filters %}
...
{% with subdata=eachObj.key3|json_loads %}
  {{ subdata.name }}
{% endwith %}
```

Although I'm not sure your approach is right, you didn't really tell us the reason you have json there

Comment: I wanted to parse a string to JSON in template. How do I use isinstance for that?

Comment: @MaruthiEranki ok, try this ^^

Comment: I'm actually storing a dictionary in data base as a long text. That is how I'm getting that json as a string over there.

Comment: @MaruthiEranki if you used `JSONField` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield , you should get the data as dict and not json, when you get `queryset.objects`, so you wouldn't need it

Comment: I found out a way to parse that in template itself. I learnt something about {% load %}. Thanks for your suggestion.